# Completly reducible representations : various questions (link with clebsch-gordan)

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I have some very basic question to improve my (also very basic) comprehension of representation theory.

We consider a completly reducible representation.

In the pdf course I follow, they consider $E_1$ and $E_2$ vectors space and they consider a representation : $D=D_1 \otimes D_2 \in E=E_1 \otimes E_2$

As the representation is completly reducible, we have :

$D=\oplus_j D_j$

Where the $D_j$ are irreducible representation.

And now, they say something I misunderstand.

We note irreducible and inequivalents representations by an indice $\rho$.

And we have :

$$ D=\oplus_\rho m_\rho D^{(\rho)}$$

$m_\rho$ is called the multiplicity of the representation.

My questions are :

- They said all this by saying that $D=D_1 \otimes D_2$, but I don't see why it is important to have a tensor product ? It is not necessary at all here ?
- What is this multiplicity ? I don't understand. I understand the equation $D=\oplus_j D_j$ by a block matrix :

$$ D(g)=\left[
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
D_1(g) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
0 & D_2(g) & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & ...  & 0 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & D_n(g) \\
\hline
\end{array}
\right], g \in G $$

Where the $D_i(g)$ are square matrices than can have any dimension. The $D_i$ are irreducible representation, thus we can't have another stable space than $V_i$ or ${0}$ for all $g \in G$ at the same time. I call $V_i$ the vector space where $D_i$ lives.

**Is the multiplicity representing the fact that I can have $D_i$ and $D_k$ representations that have the same dimension and are in addition equivalent ?**

But if it is the case, even if they live in a space of same dimension, I can't regroup them as we can see with my block matrix that they don't live in the same "part" of the space. If I call $(e_1...e_n)$ a basis of my whole space $E$,the $D_i$ would live on $Span(e_i...e_{i+p})$ and $D_k$ on $Span(e_k...e_{k+p})$. So I don't get the point...

- Finally, do you agree with me if I say that it is possible to have 2 inequivalent and irreducible representations living in a space of same dimension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are discussing representations of finite groups, or some class of associative algebras whose representations you know to be all completely reducible. In this case $D$ will decompose into a direct sum of irreducible representations just because it is a representation, not because it's a tensor product of two representations.

*Multiplicity* does mean exactly what you think: some of your summands $D_j$ might be isomorphic to each other. For example, given an irreducible representation $(\rho, V)$, you can form $D=\rho\oplus\rho$ which acts on $V\oplus V$. So $D$ decomposes into irreducibles, but both the summands are isomorphic. Note *isomorphic* as representations. In your example if $D_1\simeq D_2$ (so that the first two blocks in your matrix $D(g)$ have the same entries for all $g\in G$), you are correct that they act on two different subspaces. They act however in the same way. In general it's an interesting question with what multiplicity a representation appears with, and there are lots of interesting answers.

Yes, a group can have two irreducible representations of the same degree that are not equivalent: take the trivial representation and the $\mathrm{sgn}$ representation of the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$.

Finally, note that two representations being equivalent means in particular there's a linear isomorphism between them, so you don't have to say "same dimension and in addition equivalent."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "you can form D=ρ⊕ρD=ρ⊕ρ which acts on V⊕V [...] you are correct that they act on two different subspaces". Then I don't understand the notation $D=\oplus_\rho m_\rho D^{(\rho)}$. Indeed when we write this, at fixed $\rho$ we have $m_\rho$ matrix **that live in the same space**. This notation implicates this. So do I have to understand this $\oplus$ differently than just a direct sum ?

Comment: do you agree with me if I say that it is not exactly a direct sum when we have $\oplus m_\rho D^{(\rho)}$ as they don't act on the same subspaces ???

Comment: In fact I got my point. I just thought the notation meant that I would have at fixed $\rho$ : the matrix $m_\rho * D^{\rho}$ at the $\rho$ block diagonal position but it is not the case, I will have $m_\rho$ matrices at different block diagonal position so there is no problem.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it. You have it. In fact the following notations are all equivalent (I will write $D^{(\rho)}$ as $D_{\rho}$): $D=\bigoplus_{\rho}m_{\rho}D_{\rho}=\bigoplus D_{\rho}^{\oplus m_{\rho}}=D_{\rho_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus D_{\rho_1}\oplus D_{\rho_2}\oplus D_{\rho_2}\oplus\cdots\oplus D_{\rho_2}\oplus\cdots$, where there are $m_{\rho_1}$ summands in the first group, $m_{\rho_2}$ in the second and so on.